# How can I make a flexbox container that stretches to fit wrapped items?

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like a `flex-direction: column;` flexbox container whose width grows to fit the containing elements.

[In this codepen:](http://codepen.io/justinmc/pen/ZYwWMz)

[image: Screenshot of codepen]

The grey div is the flexbox container, and the red divs are contained inside and layed out in columns with flexbox.  The grey div needs to expand/contract its width to perfectly contain the red children divs.  Is this possible?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 290px;
  align-content: flex-start;
  padding: 2px;
  background: grey;
}
.child {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## "Solution"

I use the term solution lightly as this is **insanely** difficult to do without fixed rows like Tomas suggested *(i.e. without altering the HTML to a more conventional style)*, or generally without some high degree of hacking. Furthermore, the height halves unless there are 2 rows completed and the containing div cannot be reduced in size reliably; comment out child 7 and see what happens. Then when you also uncomment 8 see that it goes back to 'normal'.

[I have been messing around for an hour or so and the best I can come up with is in this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/7dk55801/3/)

---

## I'd like to offer a little background

The default `flex-flow` is `row nowrap`, this sets a certain width `x` on the element lucky enough to receive that rule. It appears that in this case changing the `flex-flow` to `column` **does not** reset the width `x` defined on that element. The element takes the width `x` as if it were `flex-flow: row nowrap` (try this for yourself).

There's a whole heap of width inheritance issues that stem from this, we cannot set the `flex-basis` property (it's not meant to behave like this I believe) so we need to wrap everything in another element `.container` which we can define width on, and put the actual column styles on a `.row` element instead. However, `.container` will not shrink either. At best we have our column properly defined in width with the `.container`(ing) element for both doing it's own thing.

Thus we require a pseudo element `::after` to provide the background with correct width, including some `margin` and `calc()` hacks to simulate padding.

I could type a lot more but I don't think this is a viable solution at all, really just a 'proof' of how it cannot be done nicely.

If you wanted to add more rows you'd have to change the width from 50% for 2 (1/2), to 33% for 3 (1/3) etc... it's not really as scaleable as editing the HTML itself.

So to conclude, there's a working demo for 2 rows only but for now this doesn't seem plausible with that current HTML markup structure.

Comment: Thanks, I was pulling my hair out over this too.  At least this shows it's pretty much impossible, so I guess that's the answer right now.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't set a width behavior of parent element. Set *.container* display property to inline-block and for each *.row* element add display: flex property.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 290px;
  padding: 2px;
  background: grey;
}
.row{
  display:flex;
}
.child {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, but in my case I'm looking for something that allows me to keep the given html structure. That way you could output the children as you iterate over a list for example, with no other processing to do.